# No Sound in right speaker

Tags: 11.04, sound, laptop

I have a Acer Travelmate 5742G.
fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 32bit.

I have no sound in the rights speaker. Only sound in the left speaker (onboard speakers)

How can I fix this please?

Comment: You sure it's not something with your laptop? Is there anyway you can confirm that? (Maybe booting from a liveCD of a different distribution or a different Ubuntu version and see that both speakers work.) Because I'm also having an Issue like that, but it's because there's something wrong with the speakers.

Comment: I agree with Dananjaya. Before spending a lot of time looking for driver/software issues, you might want to make sure the hardware is OK.  Is the problem still there if you use headphones?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same model and it has only left speaker, I mean it has only one speaker at all! So, check if you have the second on, it is quite ridiculous, I know, but that's it!

Answer (score 0):

try using the pavucontrol to check the volume of the right channel (apt-get install pavucontrol if you dont have it). It should be on the output devices tab. click on the small lock to prevent them to have different volumes.